# How to Sum total of data that have a same value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to sum the total of status in my database. If I have status = 0 I want it count all of them instances of status = 0. I have tried this code but the total sum doesn't match with my database.

```
SELECT t.date as Date, COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) as Transaction, SUM(t.status=0) as Success, COUNT(DISTINCT r.id) as Request, SUM(r.status=0) as RequestSuccess 
FROM transfer_tx_201503 AS t,request_tx_201503 AS r 
WHERE t.time >='00:00:00' AND t.time <= '$searchterm' AND t.date=r.date 
GROUP BY `date`
```

Comment: What query do you compare to when you say that the total sum is wrong?

Comment: the query is right when i doesn't combine of two table.

Comment: You have an implicit `JOIN`. Depending on values of `date` and `time` your combined table could have "*duplicate*" rows that contribute to your total.

Comment: can you show me the query ? i am confuse with the function of join.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query, properly written, is:

```
SELECT t.date as Date, COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) as Transaction, SUM(t.status=0) as Success, COUNT(DISTINCT r.id) as Request, SUM(r.status=0) as RequestSuccess 
FROM transfer_tx_201503 t JOIN
     request_tx_201503 r 
     ON t.date = r.date 
WHERE t.time >='00:00:00' AND t.time <= '$searchterm' 
GROUP BY `date`
```

(Notice the `ON` clause and explicit `JOIN` . . . this is the right way to join two tables together.)

Your problem is that you are getting a cartesian product for a given `date`, because multiple rows in each table match the date.  The best solution is to pre-aggregate the results:

```
SELECT t.date as Date, t.Transaction, t.Success, r.Request, r.RequestSuccess 
FROM (select date, count(*) as transaction, sum(t.status = 0) as success
      from transfer_tx_201503 t
      group by date
     ) t JOIN
     (select date, count(*) as Requestion, SUM(r.status = 0) as RequestSuccess
      from request_tx_201503 r 
      group by date
     ) r
     ON t.date = r.date 
WHERE t.time >='00:00:00' AND t.time <= '$searchterm' ;
```

Note that you no longer need the outer `group by`.  You can also include the `where` clause in each subquery.  That will probably improve performance, if that is an issue.